Which API returns the message for NTSTATUS?
Is there a Windows API returning the message text for NTSTATUS codes?
i.e. something similar to WinAPI: FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, ....)
FormatMessage doesn't work - neither on the ntstatus code, nor on HRESULT_FROM_NT(ntstatus).

This MS article suggests that FormatMessage should be able to convert NTSTATUS to string. There is an example there how to use it. Are you sure it does not work ?

The important point in the KB entry is to use FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE and pass the result of LoadLibrary("NTDLL.DLL") for the lpSource parameter.

This should be posted as an answer.

According to this MS KB article, FormatMessage API can be used to convert NTSTATUS code to text.
The article above contains a complete usage example.
Important notes for the usage:

dwFlags (the 1st param) should include:
FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE


lpSource (the 2nd param) should be the HMODULE of "NTDLL.DLL" (can be acquired via LoadLibrary("NTDLL.DLL")).

Another alernative if you are using C++, is to use std::system_category (available since C++ 11).
#include <system_error>  // required for std::system_category
#include <iostream>

// ...

std::string message1 = std::system_category().message(STATUS_TIMEOUT);
std::cout << message1 << std::endl;

Output:
The wait operation timed out.

Note: not all NTSTATUS values are supported by std::system_category(), for some you will get "unknown error".
